# In how many ways can we split a set of $n$ elements into $n$ groups by splitting them in a random place each time?

Tags: combinatorics

If we start with $n$ elements and at each step split them into $2$ parts randomnly and repeat with both sub-parts until parts of only $1$ element are left, in how many different ways can these elements be separated?
I made a mistake we don't split them in half we split them in a random place.

Comment: Can you specify a rule, how to split a set with an odd number of elements? For example how to split a set with say $5$ elements.

Comment: "split $n$ elements"... Don't you mean "split a **set** of $n$ elements"? And how can the (sub)sets be distinguished? On base of their elements or e.g. only on base of their cardinality?

Comment: On base of their elements e.g. for the set ${1,2,3}$ we can first split it as ${1|2,3}$ and then ${1|2|3}$ so that would be one way or we can split it as ${1,2|3}$ and then ${1|2|3}$ so 2 ways total

Comment: And how about $1,3\mid2$ followed by $1\mid3\mid2$? Overlooking that possibility was the source of my mistake.

Comment: I think the question needs to be [edit]ed to explain it clearer, based on the comment by @user3572917.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a log of wood which you want to cut into $n$ parts.

A little thought will show that you need to make $(n-1)$ cuts.

These cuts can be in any order, thus # of ways to do it = $(n-1)!$

e.g. if $n = 4,$ you need $(4-1)! = 3\times2\times1 = 6$

Comment: Seems like this should have been accepted being a closed form.

Comment: But once you split it in 2 and 2 there is only 1 way to split it in 4 so I think the correct answer would be 5

Comment: For n = 4, you have to cut at three points, 1,2,3. When you first split in the middle at 2, you can either go 2-1-3 or 2-3-1.

Comment: I am taking a scale of length 4 units (say) with three intermediate random points marked 1,2,3, where the cuts are made.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there are $x_n$ ways if the number of elements is $n$. Then $x_1=1$ and:$$x_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i\times x_{n-i}$$

where term $x_i\times x_{n-i}$ corresponds with a *first* split: $1,\dots,i\mid i+1,\dots,n$.

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry. Reconsider your acceptance.

Comment: What is the mathematical name for this problem? Thx.

Comment: What is the mistake?

Comment: My solution only works under the extra condition that numbered elements are split in such a way that the element-numbers is the subsets are consecutive. E.g. it gives $x_3=2$, corresponding to $1\mid2,3$ followed by $1\mid2\mid3$ and $1,2\mid3$ followed by $1\mid2\mid3$, but there is also the possibility $1,3\mid2$ followed by $1\mid3\mid2$.

Comment: That is a condition included in the problem it was my mistake I forgot to add it

Comment: @user3572917, it seems that you have not included the condition yet.